# How can i use sscanf to get int with / separator

Tags: c, scanf

I have this character string  `"  Running OnAirSegmentProgress: 1610/15464 "`.
How can I extract the first `int` with `sscanf`  just before the `"/"` 
noting that this integer is changing periodically?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: do you want to extract only the first one, the first and the second, or an arbitrary sequence of ints separated by `/`?

Comment: for example in this case i want to extract 1610  and so on just the first integer before  the  /

Comment: Functions that may be of use: `strchr`, `isdigit`, `sscanf`, `strtol`

Comment: how can i  use it with sscanf

Comment: If the input was `" Run 123 456 OnAirSegment / Progress: 1610 /15464 "`, what should be the result?

Comment: the result is 1610

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably one the the most robust *format strings* for reading the 1st integer value from a string with non-numeric characters preceding the integer is to use a *character class* comprised of anything not-a-digit combined with the *assignment suppression operator* `'*'` to *read and discard* all non-digit characters up to the first digit, e.g.

```
    "%*[^0-9] %d"
```

By doing so, you eliminate any reliance on what characters may, or may not, come before your needed integer. (so long as a digit cannot appear before the first digit in your integer value)

Further, when using `sscanf` you *must* **check the return** to validate that the expected number of conversions did in fact take place before you can have confidence you have valid data. Make this a habit with all conversions. If you are not validating, you are simply programming by luck or happy-accident. Don't rely on chance in your coding -- validate.

A short example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    char *s = "  Running OnAirSegmentProgress: 1610/15464 ";
    int wanted;

    if (sscanf (s, "%*[^0-9] %d", &wanted) == 1)
        printf ("integer: %d\n", wanted);
    else
        fputs ("error: failed to parse integer.\n", stderr);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/parse1stint
integer: 1610
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a quick solution but it works:

```
int main(void)
{
    int firstNum = 0, secondNum = 0;
    char string[100] = "Running OnAirSegmentProgress: 1610/15464";
    sscanf(string, "%*s %*s %d/%d", &firstNum, &secondNum);
    printf("%d\n", firstNum);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char str[100]="Running OnAirSegment Progress: 1610/15464";
    int value,none;
    sscanf ( str, "%*[a-z A-Z: ] %d/%d", &value,&none);
    printf("%d %d",value,none);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @chux. Yes you are right. I edited.But I left an extra space.